# Export results from Oracle Db into unix share daily

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to run a daily query against an Oracle database and export the results into a unix share.  Ive been doing this manually for two weeks now and Im looking to automate the task

Comment: Yes; it is; [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF) probably but you haven't stated what type of file you want so just look through the list of [all packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/toc.htm), they'll be one that can help you.

Comment: .csv or .txt would be fine...Thanks Ben I will read through the inforamtion you supplied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this you should use 'shell script here document'.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
dbuser='root';
dbpasswd='root123';
sqlplus -S $user/$passwd@$database<<END
SPOOL /tmp/mydata
select * from table;
SPOOL OFF
END
```

Here sqlplus -S is so that you will not get licensing statement of oracle.(Silent Login).

Put this script for cron job. Once you get your data in "/tmp/mydata" use awk or shell to process it. I always found awk better choice to process such results.

Comment: Thanks Virus, I will be trying this out today and will update back

Answer (score 0):

If the script isn't require too much formatting then you can use sql*plus also.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/toc.htm